# Atom IDE Default Language Syntax Highlighting

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I'm pretty new to programming and have started using Atom for coding. I want to make python the default for code color highlighting so I don't have to change it every time I start a new file, but I haven't found out how to do that yet. I have a couple screenshots of what I'm talking about.

The first is a screen-grab from the bottom right corner, and the second is the window that comes up when that is selected. It shows python because I have already changed it for this file. I would like python to be the default.

[image: Screen Grab 1]
[image: Screen Grab 2]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what OS you are using you can go do this:

macOS: `Atom -> Init Script`

Windows: `File -> Init Script`

This will make a window appear that is titled `init.coffee`

Then underneath the commented section add these lines of code:

```
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
   unless editor.getPath()
       editor.setGrammar(atom.grammars.grammarForScopeName('source.python'))
```

Save and restart Atom.

source: [here](https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/set-default-language-in-atom-to-python/16455)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, so it was Edit -> Init Script...

But I got it! Thanks!