# Is there a way to set the default language as python in atom

Tags: atom-editor

So I started using atom code editor and everytime I open a new file its default type is plain text.It becomes a pain to change it everytime as I select python as the file type.Is there a shortcut key to change it directly or maybe some change in the scripts of atom

Comment: [Duplicated question. Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45020855/atom-ide-default-language-syntax-highlighting)